# SQL trigger wont run when I execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have written an SQL trigger that first Validates that an item has a Discount Price and If not it has to raise an error. The second part of the trigger needs to check the date of the document and ensure that the item is not expired. My trigger will do one but not both at the same time. Can anyone assist, I have my code below.

```
SELECT @DocType = DocType, @OrderDate = OrderDate, @InvDate = InvDate 
FROM InvNum 
WHERE AutoIndex = @Invoice

SELECT @DocState = DocState 
FROM InvNum 
WHERE AutoIndex = @Invoice

SELECT @Account = AccountID 
FROM InvNum 
WHERE AutoIndex = @Invoice

SELECT  @Valid = iStockCodeID 
FROM _btblInvoiceLines 
LEFT JOIN InvNum ON iInvoiceID = AutoIndex 
LEFT JOIN _etblVDAR ON iARAPID = AccountID 
LEFT JOIN _etblVDLnAR ON iVDID = IDVD
WHERE iStockID = @StockCode AND iARAPID = @Account

SELECT  @ValidPO = iStockCodeID 
FROM _btblInvoiceLines 
LEFT JOIN InvNum ON iInvoiceID = AutoIndex 
LEFT JOIN _etblVDAP ON iARAPID = AccountID 
LEFT JOIN _etblVDLnAP ON iVDID = IDVD
WHERE iStockID = @StockCode AND iARAPID = @Account

select @dExpDate=dexpdate 
from _btblInvoiceLines 
inner join _etblVDLnAR on _btblInvoiceLines.iStockCodeID = _etblVDLnAR.iStockID 
where _btblInvoiceLines.iStockCodeID = iStockCodeID
-- BEGIN
--  IF (@DocType = 4 OR @DocType = 1) AND @DocState <> 7
--  BEGIN
--   IF @Module = 0 AND @Valid IS NULL 
--   BEGIN
--    RAISERROR ('Message from Management: 
--You are not allowed to select an item for which no Volume Discount Price has been entered for this customer.
--The transaction will be rolled back. ', 16, 1)
--    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
--    End
IF (@DocType = 4  AND @DocState IN (0,1,2,3)) AND @OrderDate>=@dExpDate
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Message from Management: 
Please check expiry date! . ', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END    
END
END
END
```

Comment: Show us your trigger code

Comment: So, you either are using a cursor in your trigger or you are failing to consider multiple rows on the trigger. Either way, you need to revisit your design and change it to a set based behavior.